# Cannot import all .JSON files into MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, twitter, cygwin

**ISSUE RESOLVED**: So it turns out that I never actually had an issue in the first place. When I did a count on the number of records to determine how many records I should expect to be imported, blank spaces between .json objects were being added towards the total record count. However, upon importing, only the objects with content were moved. I'll just leave this post here for reference anyway. Thank you to those who contributed regardless.

---

I have around ~33GB of .JSON files that were retrieved from Twitter's streaming API stored in a local directory. I am trying to import this data into a MongoDB collection. I have made two attempts:

First attempt: read through each file individually (~70 files). This successfully imported 11,171,885/ 22,343,770 documents.

```
import json
import glob
from pymongo import MongoClient

directory = '/data/twitter/output/*.json'
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.twitter
collection = db.test

jsonFiles = glob.glob(directory)
for file in jsonFiles:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        for line in f.read().split("\n"):
                if line:
                        try:
                                lineJson = json.loads(line)
                        except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError) as e:
                                pass
                        else:
                                postid = collection.insert(lineJson)
                                print 'inserted with id: ' , postid

        f.close()
```

Second attempt: Concatenate each .JSON file into one large file. This successfully import 11,171,879/ 22,343,770 documents.

```
import json
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient
import sys

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.tweets
collection = db.test

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, '/data/twitter/blob/historical-tweets.json')

try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                for line in f.read().split("\n"):
                        if line:
                                try:
                                        lineJson = json.loads(line)
                                except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError) as e:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                        postid = collection.insert(lineJson)
                                        print 'inserted with id: ' , postid

                f.close()
```

The python script did not error out and output a traceback, it simply stopped running. Any ideas to what could be causing this? Or any alternative solutions to importing the data more efficiently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the mongodb logs?

Comment: Yes, it seems that everything is running properly.

Comment: So, it just suddenly fails? You've got plenty of disk space? Are you sure the file is valid and that each line is unique? It's very interesting that it's essentially half the file is loaded in both cases. (That's a very strange coincidence if it's not related to the issue).

Comment: Yes, it's definitely an interesting situation...which is why I can't seem to wrap my mind around it. I have a theory I wanted to test though. In the past, opening up a .json files in a .txt placed each .json object on an individual line and there was a line of space between each record. I wonder if the count function added up the spaces towards the total records, but upon importing, only the records with content were moved. I'm exporting to .txt right now and I'll take a look at how many records I should really be expecting to import.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file one line at the time. Is each line really valid json? If not, json.loads will trace and you are hiding that trace with the pass statement.

Comment: I completely overlooked that. That should resolve the traceback issue and give me some ideas but the importing problem will more than likely occur again. This script takes quite awhile to run, but I'll edit my post with the traceback once it reaches that point. Thanks

Comment: If you are open to solving your problem with another tool, you may want to take a look at mongoimport: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

"The mongoimport tool provides a route to import content from a JSON, CSV, or TSV export created by mongoexport, or potentially, another third-party export tool."

Comment: This was my first option as it would have been a more efficient method. However, the Mongoimport/export functions have size limitations on the documents being moved which is quite unfortunate.

Comment: You are aware that MongoDB maximum document size is 16MB? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/